# How to jump to last row, when I have empty cells in between?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I run the below script, it does not jump into last non empty cell, but it jumps in the middle. I believe I have some empty cells between rows and that is the issue

```
function onOpen() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Raw data')
    s.setActiveRange(s.getRange(s.getRange('A:A').getValues().filter(String).length, 1))
}
```

[image]

See attached  screenshot

Comment: Can you use s.getLastRow() instead to get the last row of the sheet with content ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you have empty rows  in between the column and `filter` filters out those rows as well. You can use [`Sheet#getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getlastrow) instead of filtering all A:A values:

```
s.setActiveRange(s.getRange(s.getLastRow(), 1))
```

Comment: it shows the following errror   "Exception: The parameters (number,number) don't match the method signature for"